# How to count how many JSON object with { } in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to count and list every JSON item by numbers. Is it possible to count the item by the { }? For example, it will search for the first {} and set it as the first item and so on.

[image]

**Expected output:**
[image]

**Code**

```
  tmp = json.dumps(file_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent="\t") + "\n" + "\n"

  reviewjson.insert(END, tmp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert your json to python dict easily, that should get you job done

`tmp_dict = json.loads(tmp)`

Comment: It doesnt show in proper format, i want it to add a counting number for each of the data. For example 1[json], 2[json] and so on.

Comment: @Johnnyyy Once you have it as a Python object you have plenty of tools to format it any way you want. Counting `{`s will get very difficult if your data has nested `{ }` in it.

Comment: @BoarGules Alright thanks for the explanation. I will worked on python object instead